# xsl:if test= somethign and something

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to figure out how to test that 2 conditions are met in a XSL if statement.

```
 <xsl:if test="NewDataSet/CallMetrics/CallsinQueue &lt; 10 
               and NewDataSet/CallMetrics/CallsinQueue &gt; 10">
      <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#009900</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:if>
```

Comment: @Denoteone: **Both conditions are mutually exclusive**, unless there are more than one `CallsinQueue` element, why the `and` operator then?

Comment: They are not exclusive. "10" value will be matched, but count is still missing. Looks creepy.

Comment: @Denoteone, you have successfully created code that tests that 2 conditions are met in an XSL "if" statement (although it's a strange pair of conditions, as @Alej said). What is the problem or question? If it is not behaving as you expect, how is it behaving and how does that differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: LarsH, yeah, corrected already.

Comment: @Flack: corrected what? 10 won't be matched. (Don't know what you mean about count. He's testing the value of CallsInQueue, not the count of them.)

Comment: I meant that condition will be true with count() present on checks and when CallsinQueue have 10 occurences in this location path. I put this into words quite clumsily though.

Comment: @Flack: Off topic, but if there is one and only `CallsinQueue` element, then it can be one `CallsinQueue` element, at the same time, lesser than ten - `(-INF,10)` - and greater than 10 - `(10,+INF)`. If there is more than one then it could be one meeting the first condition and other meeting the second condition.

Comment: There is *no* question here! Only a statement. Voted to `C L O S E`

Comment: Gosh, should have been more careful with reading. Won't remove previous comments as a sign of an accepted shame :)

Comment: Sorry to waste your time guys... my question was about the "and" in the if statement. I was wondering if it was like other languages when you use "&&" I didn't even notice I had the value of "10" in both of my evaluations. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Your test condition will return false for all values including 10

```
 x   x<10   x>10   x<10 & x>10
---  ----   ----   -----------
 8   true   false     false
10   false  false     false
12   false  true      false
```

Perhaps you meant to use `or` instead of `and`?

EDIT: If `NewDataSet/CallMetrics/CallsinQueue` is a sequence of nodes, the rules for general comparison state that the each comparison will return true if any node's value satisfies the condition.  So the entire expression is true only if the sequence contains one or more nodes with value < 10 AND one or more nodes with value > 10.  That doesn't seem to be what was intended.

Comment: ...unless there are multiple elements `NewDataSet/CallMetrics/CallsinQueue`, which is possible in XSLT, as Alejandro already correctly pointed out.

Comment: In that case, based on the rules for General Comparisons, it will return true only if the sequence has at least one member whose value is less than 10 and one member with value greater than 10.  Somehow I doubt that's the intended question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check whether CallMetrics contains both a CallsInQueue with a value less than 10 and a CallsInQueue with a value greater than 10 then this should do it:

```
<xsl:if test="NewDataSet/CallMetrics[CallsinQueue &lt; 10] 
               and NewDataSet/CallMetrics[CallsinQueue &gt; 10"]>
      <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#009900</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

The [...] operator checks for existence of a node matching the specified condition.

Comment: In fact, that correction isn't needed. As it was pointed out before, node-set comparison are existencial comparison.